# GetDate in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I'm having some trouble using regular expression to get date in a string.
Example :

```
 string text = "75000+ Sept.-Oct. 2004";
MatchCollection dates = Regex.Matches(text, @"[0-9]{5,}[+][\s](jan|feb|fev|mar|apr|avr|may|mai|jun|jui|jul|jui|aug|aoû|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\.][\-](jan|feb|fev|mar|apr|avr|may|mai|jun|jui|jul|jui|aug|aoû|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\.]\s[0-9]{4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This code is matching with my current string but i would like to get in my matchcollection, "Sept 2004" and "Oct 2004" in order to parse it in 2 datetime.

If anyone have any idea, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the lengths of the array, etc. You should get the idea

```
 string text = "75000+ Sept.-Oct. 2004";
 MatchCollection dates = Regex.Matches(text, @"[0-9]{5,}[+][\s](jan|feb|fev|mar|apr|avr|may|mai|jun|jui|jul|jui|aug|aoû|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\.][\-](jan|feb|fev|mar|apr|avr|may|mai|jun|jui|jul|jui|aug|aoû|sept|oct|nov|dec)[\.]\s([0-9]{4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 Console.WriteLine(dates[0].Groups[1] + " " + dates[0].Groups[3]);
 Console.WriteLine(dates[0].Groups[2] + " " + dates[0].Groups[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't know I can get each group of my regular expression.